# Authlogic and declarative authorizsation

Tags: ruby, authentication, authorization, declarative

I have a rails application based on Authlogic with LDAP for authentification, and declarative authorization for roles requirements.

The problem is when i put filter resource_access in my controller, i got this error :

undefined method `current_user'....

I had define the method current_user on the application_controller

Any help ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I can't recommend this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic) highly enough.  It takes you step-by-step through how to setup authlogic for your rails app -- including defining the current_user variable.